# How to correctly place return False statement in a Tree method?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, tree

Here is the function that returns `True` if there exists a Tree node that has value passed the test test, and returns `False` if there's no such value. Here I am having problem with the first docstring example `def greater_than_nine(n): return n > 9`. As you can see, there is a 10.5 that is greater than 9 so the contains_test_passer should return True. But I have a hard time placing the return False statement. For now the function always returns False. Could someone please help?

```
def contains_test_passer(t, test):
"""
Return whether t contains a value that test(value) returns True for.

@param Tree t: tree to search for values that pass test
@param (object)->bool test: predicate to check values with
@rtype: bool

>>> t = descendants_from_list(Tree(0), [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 10.5], 4)
>>> def greater_than_nine(n): return n > 9
>>> contains_test_passer(t, greater_than_nine)
True
>>> def even(n): return n % 2 == 0
>>> contains_test_passer(t, even)
True
"""
if test(t.value):
    return True
else:
    for x in t.children:
        contains_test_passer(x,test)

    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

because `contains_test_passer` returns a boolean you just need to catch the value for the recursive calls:

```
for x in t.children:
    if contains_test_passer(x,test):
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `any`:

```
return test(t.value) or any(contains_test_passer(x, test) for x in t.children)
```

That will return True if any of the calls to `contains_test_passer` return True, and False otherwise. It will behave <s>exactly</s> almost the same as the code in the answer by Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, but I think it is more readable.

Comment: There's a problem. How about the value of the tree root? Where does it go?

Comment: this is actually more efficient then doing the for loop manually since the iteration part is handled in `C` instead of `python` code, and it lets you define this function in a single line: `return test(t.value) or any(...)` Although I'd argue that the explicit for loop is easer to read

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen For me it's the other way around, but I can see why it might.

Comment: @CoolKid See my edit (stolen from Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's comment). You can also have your original if-else structure and just have the `return any(...)` statement in the else clause.